# Redemption dll registration

Tags: outlook-redemption

I want to register Redemption.dll in server machine which is windows 2003 and 64 bit machine also having outlook there, but i get the following Error and not able to register it in that machine.

**FULL_PATH/Redemption.dll was loaded,but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.
This file cannot be registered.**

where it goes wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u manage to fix this problem? I can't get it to work too!

Comment: Does it perhaps have to do with the fact that redemption is 32 bit? What method are you using to register the dll?

Comment: Hi, 
You can register dll in 64 bit machine as following:
In case of Vista 64 bit, use %SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe to register the dll, 
and not %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\regsvr32.exe (which is a 64 bit exe)

Comment: It sure sounds like you have a corrupted instance of redemption.dll. Also make sure that the bitness of Outlook/MAPI system matches the bitness of the dll (Redemption comes in both 32 and 64 bit flavors). See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject

Answer (score 1):

The dll needs to export a function named "DllRegisterServer" which registers it as a COM server so that COM can do it's thing.

regsvr32 could not find this function when it loaded the DLL.

This implies that Redemption.dll is not a COM component.

Comment: Redemption is most definitely a COM-DLL.

Comment: did you check if it exports the DllRegisterServer function using dumpbin?

Comment: Please just check the Redemption homepage: http://dimastr.com/redemption especially the section entitled "How Outlook Redemption works". Quote: "Redemption is a regular COM library; once registered on the system [...]" We have been using Redemption in our products for years and please be assured that it IS a COM-DLL: It is installed by registering it via regsvr32.exe or by calling `DllRegisterServer` and it is used by creating instances of various COM servers contained therein using the `CoCreateInstance` API. Not sure why you couldn't get it to work.